# How can I format my date value?

Tags: javascript

Hi I would like to ask anyone if how can I format my date into this format yyyy-mm-dd. Currently I'm having this format `Sat Feb 08 2014 08:00:00 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)`

Here is my code for my date format:

```
var ss = new Date(rangeTo);  //Where rangTo is a textbox
var newss = new Date(ss.setDate(ss.getDate() + 1));
```

Comment: http://blog.justin.kelly.org.au/simple-javascript-function-to-format-the-date-as-yyyy-mm-dd/

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has fairly limited capbilities for formatting dates, so I recomment using something like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: It would be good to provide an example of how to do so, if you are going to suggest using Moment.js.